# Infopath 2013 repeating section or table

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have a repeating table and section. I want to be able to grab that information from the repeating table and add it to my SharePoint list.

It seems that I can only get the first row to show up in my SharePoint list and when someone adds another row or more informaiton it does not go to my SharePoint list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to process each row in the repeating table, you will need to iterate through the collection of rows in the code behind and write the data to SharePoint.

Here's a tutorial on how to do this: [How to submit the rows of a repeating table in InfoPath to a SharePoint list](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-submit-items-rows-repeating-table-infopath-sharepoint-list.htm)

The key tidbit that you're looking for is how to use the [XPathNodeIterator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx):

```
// Retrieve the rows of the repeating table
XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator rows = root.Select("/my:myFields/my:rows/my:row", NamespaceManager);

// Loop through the rows of the repeating table
while (rows.MoveNext())
{
    // Do something awesome...
    // like getting a value from the row:
    string title = rows.Current.SelectSingleNode("my:title", NamespaceManager).Value;
}
```

You may also find this article on MSDN helpful: [How to: Work with the XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa945227%28v=office.14%29.aspx)